# Permission for publish field on a translation

Tags: 9, transliteration

the website is a multilingual website, and the `Publish` field is checked as translateable.
user one, can see the `Publish` checkbox on translation and can change it.

but in the other role (let's call it content admin), when editing the translation all fields are there and editable but only the "Publish" checkbox does not show for the user.

I almost gave all translation and edition permission to the "content admin" role. but still, the Publish checkbox hasn't appeared.

the question is, which permission is required to see `Publish` on a translation content?

Comment: Mmm I  too wonder this did you have a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2972308 ?
oh and happy new year mate :)

Comment: @taggartJ happy new year too!  yes, I saw it but had no success. I gave permission to the role but didn't work.
I will check the field permission access on the form building and find a way for that.